# Photovoltaic ‘Rectenna’ is it possible?

Tags: solar-cells

Video: https://youtu.be/BKyksxC_nxY

A copper wire with N and P type Silicon on it wrapped around a fiber optic thread or glass rod with light entering on end and bouncing around inside and exiting the other end of the glass fiber or rod.

Will the charge imbalance produce a back and forth effect like alternating current?[image]

Comment: Why do you think an isolated bit of n or p type silicon would have a charge imbalance?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You should explain in more detail the experimental set-up  and why there should be a charge imbalance! Also the linked video doesn't explain.

Comment: Light bounces around and only like 20% of this actually converts so this fractional amount is not grouped or evenly dispersed.

Comment: Rectennas to convert light into electric energy are possible and have been demonstrated experimentally. How the set-up you are showing is related to rectennas is completely unclear.